# Spline "motion tracking" indicators

Tags: splines

Learning blender (3.4 installed), I see people creating a spline then turning on motion tracking to view the path with arrows.  They do this with the Viewport Overlays drop-down, enabling the Motion Tracking checkbox, to get the image below.  However when I check the box my spline (a Bezier) doesn't look any different.  There are no arrows.

What mistake did I make?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, found it.  It wasn't Motion Tracking that had to be enabled, it was "Normals", at the bottom of the dialog.

[image]